# Meses en español en Ionic - ion-datetime

Tags: angular, ionic4

Estoy utilizando la etiqueta para fecha  en ionic. Con el siguiente formato Año/Mes, viéndose en el código de la siguiente forma:

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="YYYY, MMMM" ></ion-datetime>
```

Mi duda es...como colocar los **meses en español**, utilizando este formato.

Al utilizar de esa manera se visualizan los meses en inglés.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo cambiando el atributo **displayFormat**=**"YYYY, MMMM"** por **"YYYY, MMM"** y agregando el atributo **monthShortNames**="Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre" con esos valores.